# A problem to show that there are infinitely many compositions of f,g that map ℓ to m

Tags: functions

Let $n>1$ be any integer. Define $f,g$ as functions from $\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1 \}$ to $\{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$ defined as
\begin{align*} 
&f(i)=2i \pmod{n} \\ 
&g(i)=2i+1 \pmod{n} \end{align*}
Show that for any integers $\ell,m \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,n-1 \}$ , there are infinitely many compositions of $f,g$ that map $\ell$ to $m$

I have started learning relations and functions and mapping. This question is a like a bolt from the blue. I expect an answer which will help me understand how to approach such problems.

Thank you.

No answer yet..

Comment: If I were faced with this I'd try to do a special case first: $n=12$ for instance ought to be "typical".